# Highlight Numbers within specific String

Tags: excel, vba

I am totally new to this, a useful code I found here
Request a small modification to suit my requirement. actually I wish to highlight the string there in the word document and close it, but don't know how to do ?
Please help....

```
 Dim wrdApp As Object
    Dim wrdDoc As Object
    Dim startt As String
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\......")

    Dim i As Long

'For i = 1 To 6
For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    startt = Range("A" & i).Value

    Set rng1 = wrdDoc.Range
    If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:=startt) Then
        Set rng2 = wrdDoc.Range(rng1.End, wrdDoc.Range.End)
        If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="=") Then
            strTheText = wrdDoc.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
           ' MsgBox strTheText
            Sheet1.Range("F" & i).Value = startt & " " & strTheText
        End If
    End If
    Next i
   '

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see in your code where you've tried to format a substring. But you would do this similar to Excel, using the `Characters` property of the `Range` object.  Give it a try and, if you still have problems, post back with the code you've tried.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Bu to be very honest , I am not trained or educated for any programing , as long as I understand only that the sentence between two given words are getting copied in excel ,  in some cell that much I understand ... But one single code I can not write ... I tried reading g some posts I can understand but I can not write it of my own ..

Comment: I am cueious to learn but failing , basically without a training , i am putting strain on my eyes and end up with headache ..